# How cassandra is able to perform snapshot by hard link?

Tags: linux, cassandra

Reading Cassandra documentation [here](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/operations/ops_backup_restore_c.html), they say if JNA (Java Native Access) is enabled snapshots are performed by hard link.

I can't understand how a hard link can hold a point in time version of a given file since it's the file itself at inode level (at least the way I understand hard links, I may be mistaken).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

SSTable files are immutable so any hard reference will be the only state the file was ever in.

Comment: I know an SSTable can't be changed, but they can be removed and made obsolete via compaction, right?  How does the hard link solve for this?

Comment: It doesnt. It's a Snapshot in time. The state of the database at that time is the sstables that exist

Comment: @RussS just to summarise and validate it: on compaction, new sstables are created. The file names are pointing to different inodes. The snapshots, however, are still pointing to the old data. is that correct?